# Exploring Data Lake Analytics account from Visual Studio's Server explorer stops working with InternalServerError

Tags: visual-studio-2015, server-explorer, azure-data-lake

I am getting following error while expanding Azure Data Lake Analytics account from Visual Studio's Server Explorer. It was working fine but recently it stops working. I am not sure what is causing this issue and how can I resolve it. BTW, I am using VS2015.

```
Hyak.Common.CloudException: InternalServerError: Internal Server returned InternalServerError.

   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)

   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Analytics.DataLakeAnalyticsAccountOperationsExtensions.ListStorageContainers(IDataLakeAnalyticsAccountOperations operations, String resourceGroupName, String accountName, String storageAccountName)

   at Microsoft.Cosmos.ClientTools.IDECommon.WindowsAzureStorageClient.GetContainerList(String caNme, String storageAccountName, String suffix)
```

Comment: I will point the tool team to your issue and ask them to answer. It looks like the account enumeration failed for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that this happens if you have a Windows Azure Store (WAS) account linked to your Data Lake Analytics account where the key that was used to link the WAS account has expired.  If this is the case, you can remove and relink the account with the updated key and the issue should go away.  The VS tools shouldn't block expanding that node completely like it does.  That is fixed in the upcoming bits (version 2.0.6000.0).  It's likely fixed in 2.0.5000.0 also; however, I would wait about 24 hours for 2.0.6000.0 because the 5000 one has a bad regression where VS locks up if you try to open a project before loading the analytics accounts in server explorer first.

Update: the new bits are [live](http://aka.ms/ADLToolsVS)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I observed that two Data Lake Store accounts were linked with Data Lake Analytics account, and later one Data Lake Store was deleted. But after deletion, it was still appearing as linked Data Source in Data Lake Analytics account. I removed that deleted Store from  Data Lake Analytics account. But, it did not solve the problem. I am not sure how can we remove and relink store account as default store cannot be removed from Data Lake Analytics account. If I remember correctly, I had not used any key for connecting Store with Analytics account.

Comment: The new bits are live so you can give them a try.  That's correct, you can't unlink the default store account, and you shouldn't need to since it's a valid account.  Keys only applies to Windows Azure Storage accounts and not Azure Data Lake Storage.  I would think that after you unlinked the invalid account then the problem would go away.  With the new bits, are you still seeing an issue?  Is the error different?

Comment: My bad, you were right. ADLA account was linked to another storage account that did not exist. When I removed that account link, problem solved. Thanks for your help!